# How to make a floating mesh rotate?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I have a mesh (a hat) with a Rigid Body and Collision simulations.

I have a Wind force field that makes the object float but it's not rotating. How to make it rotate while floating ?

Is it possible to do this with these constraints ? Should I use Fluid simulation ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

Create two small cubes and add RigidBody to it. ( Delete rigid body on the hat).
Give two different mass to the cube.
Attached the two cubes with an "RigidBidy contrainst". And attach the hat to those cubes.

And it's work.

Comment: what do you mean by hat ?